# How can I determine which employees worked per week in 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm a beginner In SQL 2008.  I have a to figure out how many employees worked on a particular project for every week for the weeks in 2012.  I've got an employee table and it contains start and enddates for each employee.  I need to know which employees worked during every week in 2012.  So far I've got:

```
Select Count (distinct employeeid) 

From employees.employee e
left join projectname.projectname p on p.projectid=e.projectid

Where
p.name = 'Alaska'

Group by Datepart(week)
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us what columns your table has? You want the employees who worked all 52 weeks last year correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is (at least close to) what you are looking for.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.employeeid)
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN projectname p
ON e.projectid = p.projectid
WHERE p.name = 'Alaska'
  AND e.startdate <= '2012-01-01'
  AND e.enddate >= '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, startdate)
```